# How to fix 404 Not found error - nginx + Angular + Keycloak

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, keycloak

I am developing an Angular (10) app which uses Keycloak as its Identity and Access Management server. The overall flow of the application is given below,

[image]
URLs are:

Home: /meal-planner/app-info/home (accessed using http://localhost/meal-planner/app-info/home)

Contact us: /meal-planner/app-info/contact-us

Get meal plan: /meal-planner/my-plan?mode=create

Logout: Triggers a logout action to Keycloak server, and then redirects to home page

URL of intermediate page: /meal-planner/user-redirect

I am using nginx to host my application.

**MY QUESTION:** **I have the below error when it comes to nginx:**

All routes work as expected. Only localhost/meal-planner/user-redirect gives me a 404 Not found. I am assuming this is because the Keycloak is redirecting to the url. Can you please help me solve this issue?

A sample redirect url from keycloak looks like this: `http://localhost/meal-planner/user-redirect#state=b64bacb4-4e5c-4df7-8c68-0155143d5b9c&session_state=c2ba4e75-03d8-40d9-bd21-7a8c13920350&code=fa307035-87e1-4b71-bed5-1545360f65aa.c2ba4e75-03d8-40d9-bd21-7a8c13920350.8453e3d9-1c4b-45e2-9ea8-2f36445fed54`

My **nginx.conf** is as given below:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    index index.html index.htm;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    server_name ~^.*$;

    location / {
        error_log /var/log/nginx/default.error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/default.access.log;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri$args $uri$args/ index.html;
    }

####The next location block is not necessary. I added regex based location matching to server index.html for /meal-planner/user-redirect
    location ~ .*/meal-planner/user-redirect.* {
        error_log /var/log/nginx/user-redirect.error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/user-redirect.access.log;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri$args $uri$args/ index.html;
    }
}
```

**NOTE 1:** The whole application is divided into many modules. 'User Redirect' page is in a separate module, it routing is defind as:
**In user-mgmt.routing.module.ts:**

```
const userMgmtRoutes : Routes = [
        { path: 'meal-planner/user-redirect', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], component: UserRedirectComponent 
    }];
    
    @NgModule({
        imports: [RouterModule.forChild(userMgmtRoutes)],
        exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class UserMgmtRoutingModule {}
```

**NOTE 2:** I tried using hash location strategy - did not work
**In app-routing.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes : Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo:'/app-info/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'error', component: ErrorPageComponent, data: {errorMessage: 'oops, something went wrong! Let us try again ...'}},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: '/error'}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**NOTE 3:** Everything works when I run the application using ng serve.

Incase it matters, I am using docker to build and run my application:
**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.11 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build-test ----> I am deploying to a test env, not PROD. In package.json, defined as "build-test": "ng build --configuration=test"

FROM nginx:latest
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
RUN rm -rf ./*
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/mealoptimizerui/ /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

I am running the container using the command: `docker run -d -p 80:80 --name meal-planner-ui mealplanner/mealplannerui`

I can see /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html on the docker container

I see my nginx.conf at /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf

I do not see sites-enabled at /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ or /etc/nginx/sites-available/

I have installed docker on Windows 8 machine using DockerToolbox

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: The route configuration that you have mentioned is "meal-planner/meal-optimizer/user-redirect", while in case of keycloak url redirect you have "meal-planner/user-redirect". Is it typo or that is how the URL is configured?

Comment: CuriousMind - i am so sorry. It is a typo. I have updated the question. The route configuration is meal-planner/user-redirect. Will you pls be able to help? I am losing my mind since I have to finish this project and deploy it very soon

Comment: Are you using lazy load for UserMgmtRoutingModule? I don't find its reference in AppRoutingModule.

Answer (score 1):

Although I couldn't fully analyse your config, I notice that you forget to tell Nginx to redirect to the `index.html` in case of `404` so that Angular can handle the routing. When deploying a Single Page Application, this is a must.

Your Nginx config should look more or less like this:

```
server {
  ...
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  
  # Don't forget this line
  error_page 404 /index.html;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Triet. I will try this. Do you have any specific questions about the config? Do you think I can help you understand it better by adding anything - such as adding comments.

Comment: Hi, did it help? The config is fine for me so far.

Comment: Sorry Triet Doan, did not work when I tried with the nginx.conf file you gave me. I found something interesting though. I moved the routing from user-mgmt.routing.module.ts to app-routing.module.ts, when I tried localhost/meal-planner/user-redirect, it sent me back to the /app-info/home page. Does this behaviour tell you anything?